# Does a 30 days Sprint include weekends?

Tags: scrum, sprint

I am still learning more about Scrum and I have a question.

If people say the duration of the Sprint is 30 days, is the actual work 22 days (30 days - (2 weekend days * 4 weeks in a month)) or is it full 30 days of work, so that its takes more than one month to finish the Sprint? Or is there another scenario?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Scrum Guide says](https://www.scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html#events-sprint) about a Sprint that it's "a time-box of one month or less". So based on that, the sprint duration can be whatever you want it to be in that duration interval, but people usually chose weeks as their Sprint duration: one week, two weeks, three weeks, one month. And yes, that includes weekends.

When people say 30 days Sprints, they usually mean a one month Sprint, including weekends. If you choose 30 working days as the duration, that goes beyond the recommended one month maximum length for a Sprint (30 working days is about one month and two weeks on the calendar).

The most extreme case I've seen was 2 days sprints, where you had one Sprint on Monday and Tuesday, another Sprint on Wednesday and Thursday, and a Sprint on Friday and next Monday, then a Sprint on Tuesday and Wednesday, and so on... whatever floats your boat I guess :)

Comment: When you're at 2 day sprints I highly doubt that you're still doing sprint reviews and retrospectives

Comment: @Cronax: That particular team did. The client was very involved and every two days they showed him the latest deploy (he was sort of the Product Owner too). Retrospectives were not done so often, true, but they still did it every time they felt they were needed.

Answer (score 2):

Bogdan gave a good answer to the question but here's something else to think about. One of the problems you may encounter when working with a team new to Scrum is that they want to start by making sprints as long as possible "because we can't deliver anything useful in less than a month". Long sprints with an inexperienced team are counterproductive in my experience. A month is a long time for many kinds of work and if your team is inexperienced they may not come up with the best set of stories and an appropriate sprint goal straight away. It's not a good start if early mistakes in sprint planning commit the team for a whole month or force an abortive replan.

My advice is that if the team are inexperienced in Scrum then keep sprints as short as you possibly can. Apart from anything else it's a good discipline for the team to have to write smaller stories.

Answer (score 1):

We describe our sprint length as three weeks, that is the time between the start and end date. That includes the weekends, obviously we do not work in the weekend (unless there are issues). So we end up with 15 working days in the sprint. If there are national holidays (like christmas) we have two options:

1. Still have three weeks between the start and end date but with less working days in the sprint
2. We have sprint of 6 weeks (because most people are on holiday for at least 1 week) and so end up with 30 working days - holidays. If you have scheduled repetitive meetings for the scrum artifacts you can do not have to reschedule them all, just skip one. Saves a ton work

this is more information than requested, sorry :)